# Adding c++11 to Syntastic properly

Tags: c++, vim, syntastic

I am aware of the question that already exists here about this but I could not investigate by commenting because I do not have enough reputation.

So I use syntastic in vim and want to compile c++ stuff.

My vimrc looks like this:

```
 72 set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
 73 set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
 74 set statusline+=%*
 75 
 76 " let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler = 'g++'
 77 let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = ' -std=c++11'
 78 
 79 let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
 80 let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
 81 let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
 82 let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

My program looks like this:

```
    1 #include <functional>
    2 
    3 using namespace std;
    4 
    5 int f(int x){
    6         return x;
    7 }
    8 
    9 void f2(function<int(int)> f){
   10 
   11 }
   12 
   13 int main(){
   14         return 0;
   15 }
```

If i replace line 76 "clang++" instead of "g++" in my vimrc I get these errors:

```
  1 diff.cpp|11 col 6 error| variable has incomplete type 'void'                                        
  2 diff.cpp|11 col 11 error| use of undeclared identifier 'function'
  3 diff.cpp|11 col 33 error| expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
  4 diff.cpp|11 col 46 error| expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
  5 diff.cpp|11 col 48 error| expected ';' after top level declarator
```

If I simply remove line 77 and compile with g++ in I get:

```
  1 test.cpp|9 col 9 error| variable or field ‘f2’ declared void                                        
  2 test.cpp|9 col 9 error| ‘function’ was not declared in this scope
  3 test.cpp|9 col 18 error| expected primary-expression before ‘int’
```

Finally if I compile the program as it looks here I get no syntax checks at all. If I then compile I get:

```
test.cpp:9:9: error: variable or field ‘f2’ declared void
 void f2(function<int(int)> f){
         ^
test.cpp:9:9: error: ‘function’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:9:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
 void f2(function<int(int)> f){
```

Why is that and what checkers should I add to simply compile c++11 files? its really frustrating

Comment: Syntastic is a Vim script, not a C++ compiler.  It's your job to configure it to call the C++ checker of your choice, with the proper options.  Read the manual (in particular `:h syntastic-config-debug`) and the [wiki](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/C--%3A---gcc) for more information.

Comment: I know that. The question is what checkers I have to include to properly check c++11 code

Comment: Maybe I'm not precise enough here. I am confused by the syntastic output because I am pretty sure the included checkers are correct.

Comment: Syntastic doesn't know, nor care, about C++ standards.  It runs external programs, with the options you tell it to, and shows you the results in a window.  You can _see_ the command lines constructed by syntastic in the debug logs.  You can _change_ the way syntastic constructs the command lines by setting the various options.  There are no such things as a "correct checkers" or "incorrect checkers".  There are only command lines, and they can be more or less appropriate for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

> let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = ' -std=c++11'

There is a small error in line 77 of your vimrc. It should be

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = ' --std=c++11'
```

Notice two dashes before `std=c++11`